# Unable to find explicit activity class (Android Studio fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I've followed a tutorial for [Gallery](http://blog.grafixartist.com/image-gallery-app-android-studio-1-4-glide/) and [Listview](http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html)(with separated tabs inside) both working on the same fragment environment inside my navigation drawer. Now what I'm supposed to do was merged this two fragments together, so when I clicked on my Listview named "Gallery", it will show a listview of different cathegories for gallery photos. Now when I clicked on a certain listview, the app will not respond thus quiting itself in the process.

**My Code for TabGallery Fragment which is a "LISTVIEW"**

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryFragment.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Assuming that the GalleryFragment.class contains the Galleryimages**

**Now here contains the logcat**

```
02-07 11:22:06.732 30384-30384/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-07 11:22:06.740 30384-30384/? V/appproc: App process: starting thread pool.
02-07 11:22:06.757 30384-30398/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
02-07 11:22:06.760 30384-30384/? D/Proxy: setHttpRequestCheckHandler
02-07 11:22:06.781 30384-30384/? D/wangcy9: setStatusIcon occur wrong theme!
02-07 11:22:06.856 30384-30408/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-07 11:22:06.863 30384-30384/? D/ViewRootImpl: loadSystemProperties PersistDebugEvent: false RoDebugEvent: false
02-07 11:22:06.883 30384-30408/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.017_msm8916_64_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1__release_AU ()
                                               OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
                                               Build Date: 04/29/15 Wed
                                               Local Branch: mybranch9502464
                                               Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.1.3_rb1.12
                                               Local Patches: NONE
                                               Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.017 + 26a3cba + 6f69ea6 + 8bc2bc8 + 649fcde + a52cccf + dbf281f + 15f0bf8 +  NOTHING
02-07 11:22:06.884 30384-30408/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 11:22:06.898 30384-30408/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: PartialUpdate status: Disabled
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Left Align: 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Width Align: 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Top Align: 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Height Align: 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Min ROI Width: 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Min ROI Height: 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Needs ROI Merge: 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Dynamic Fps: Disabled
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Min Panel fps: 0
02-07 11:22:06.903 30384-30408/? I/qdutils: Max Panel fps: 0
02-07 11:22:06.985 30384-30384/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@28dbd8c7 time:52879049
02-07 11:22:11.553 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.guitarista.citem time:52883617
02-07 11:22:11.563 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-07 11:22:11.608 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-07 11:22:11.627 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem D/wangcy9: setStatusIcon occur wrong theme!
02-07 11:22:11.994 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem D/ViewRootImpl: loadSystemProperties PersistDebugEvent: false RoDebugEvent: false
02-07 11:22:12.117 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1d62e93e time:52884181
02-07 11:22:12.855 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
02-07 11:22:14.670 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
02-07 11:22:15.742 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.guitarista.citem time:52887806
02-07 11:22:15.744 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-07 11:22:15.746 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.guitarista.citem, PID: 30384
                                                                              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.guitarista.citem/com.example.guitarista.citem.Gallery.GalleryFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3806)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatJB.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompatJB.java:26)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:146)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:929)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:1043)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:932)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:921)
                                                                                  at com.example.guitarista.citem.Attendees.TabAllFragment$1.onItemClick(TabAllFragment.java:62)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
02-07 11:22:18.448 30384-30384/com.example.guitarista.citem I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30384 SIG: 9
```

**Now my suspicion is this line of code in logcat**

```
com.example.guitarista.citem/com.example.guitarista.citem.Gallery.GalleryFragment
```

although I've never even declared the package twice in my GalleryFragment nor I cant even declare it in my androidmanifest.xml .

Comment: You cannot open fragment by this method.

Comment: you are launching fragment by intent

Comment: So how do I achieve it? is there another option?

Comment: fragment transactions takes place through fragment manager and not through intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open like this

```
GalleryFragment fr = new GalleryFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
fr.setArguments(args);
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.gallery_fragment, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Done this inside my MainActivity before. Is this possible in a fragment?

Comment: Yes,this is the way how you launch fragment class from Activity, not through intent.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `Fragment` as an `Activity`.

> You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

This is how to add a `fragment` to a `viewGroup` of your `activity`:

```
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

You need to read more how to use `fragment` in this [Google Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

Comment: So all I have to do is implement this idea in a clickListener inside a fragment?